# C# time value instead of sample on chart graph

Tags: c#, time, charts, sample

I'm very new to programming, hope you can help me. My assignment is to make a ChartGraph i am reading a txt file in and it make the x-axis as samples. what i would like is to have time on my X-aixs instead, between every sample i have 3 ms

my code:

```
private void Se_livefeed_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<double> dataList = opsamling.getList();

        int blockSize = 1000;

        // clear the chart
        chart1.Series.Clear();

        // fill the chart
        var series = chart1.Series.Add("EKG");
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
            series.Points.AddXY(i, dataList[i]);


        var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];

        // set view range to [0,max]
        chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = dataList.Count;

        // enable autoscroll
        chartArea.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;

        // let's zoom to [0,blockSize] (e.g. [0,100])
        chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        int position = 0;
        int size = blockSize;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(position, size);

        // disable zoom-reset button (only scrollbar's arrows are available)
        chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;

        // set scrollbar small change to blockSize (e.g. 100)
        chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = blockSize;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to convert the index to the units you want to use for the x-axis.  For example, if you want to display it in milliseconds, and since you have 3 milliseconds between each sample (index):

```
    series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
        series.Points.AddXY(3 * i, dataList[i]);

    var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];

    // set view range to [0,max]
    chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = dataList.Count * 3;
```

If you want to display it in seconds:

```
    series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
        series.Points.AddXY(0.003 * i, dataList[i]);

    var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];

    // set view range to [0,max]
    chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = dataList.Count * 0.003;
```